# JavaFX get favicon with web browser?

Tags: web, javafx, browser

Hello everyone is it possible to get the favicon the website i'm on my webview? I'll prefer to not use any third party library so please give me a guide if it's possible without that.

Comment: If you have any question just comment

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet assumes that the favicon should be placed in a [Tab](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html), like most of the browsers do and it misses a few checks for simplicity. It's a method that accepts 2 arguments, an url string and a Tab, and uses the Google Favicon Service to get the image. The work of downloading the image is done by [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-boolean-) (in this case, it's done in the background):

```
void loadFavicon(String location, Tab tab) {
  try {
    String faviconUrl = String.format("http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=%s", URLEncoder.encode(location, "UTF-8"));
    Image favicon = new Image(faviconUrl, true);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(favicon);
    tab.setGraphic(iv);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex); // not expected
  }
```

}

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed `http` to `https`. Also, for those who might not have figured it out, this returns a PNG, not an ICO file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add webpages or websites to the webview quiet easily using a webengine to load the page
Here is the code you would use:

```
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
          webEngine.load("http://www.favicon.cc/");
```

If you want a full application here is an adapted version of the example on http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/LoadwebpagefromURLtoWebView.htm:

```
    package application;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Group;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    VBox root = new VBox();    
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
          webEngine.load("http://www.favicon.cc/");  
    root.getChildren().add(browser);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Well I actually mean from the website you where on. Like google's favicon.